How to use a selected slicer value to do a calculation on it and use this calculation result to filter a pivot table
I need to use two filters, YEAR and YEAR-1 values, on two distinct pivot tables. The YEAR value is selected from a slicer, for instance, 2024 and then, the first pivot table connected to this slicer filters values accordingly. Now I need a second distinct pivot table to filter values based on the YEAR-1, i.e. 2023, which, in its turn, is based on selected slicer value. Any ideas?
I am a beginner in Power Pivot and, so far, everything I tried didn't work as expected. Thank you in advance.

Share what you have tried. Ultimately for your second pivot you will need to use measures to do the previous year of the selected year in the slicer. If you have a Date table then you could use the Time Intelligence functions.
